# Ignore @JsonProperty annontation In fasterxml ObjectMapper based on Some Flag

Tags: java, json, fasterxml

I want to Ignore `@JsonProperty` annonation in *fastrxml* `ObjectMapper` based on Some Flag

For eg:

```
public class FeedData implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @JsonProperty(value="n")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty(value="i")
    private Integer id;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


}
```

I am having one flag based on output should vary

if flag is `true` 
     than json should be `{"n":"Radha","i":1}`
else if flag is `false` 
   than json should be `{"name":"Radha","id":1}`

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your object mapper depends on the flag value:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

if (!flag) {
  mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector( new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {
        @Override
        public PropertyName findNameForSerialization(Annotated a) {
            return null;
        }
    });
}
mapper.convertValue(object, FeedData.class)
```